# Is it possible in laravel 5 to show a pretty url to the user, and a practical url to the app?

Tags: routes, laravel-5, friendly-url, slug

I have this url: `mywebsite.com/user/1/edit`

I want my users to see this: `mywebsite.com/edit-your-profile/`

Is this possible when using `Route::resource('user',    'UserController');`? If yes, how do I do it :) ? I still want my app to be able to see `user/1/edit` as I use it in my middleware to prevent unauthorized access:

```
if ( \Auth::user()->id != $request->segment(2) ) {

    return  redirect()->back();

}
```

So, one pretty url for my user, a practical one for my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your explanation, I take that a user can only edit their own profile. So `mywebsite.com/user/1/edit` should NOT even be allowed.
Instead, add this in your Route.php add: `Route::get('/edit-your-profile','UserController@edit');` and hardcode `\Auth::user()->id` into your `editController` and do not even allow the user to set the id. Why bother asking them for an ID if you already know what the id must be and ALL other ids will be rejected!

PS. The html form for update should be at `@update` and the output that form should be sent to `@edit`. I just wanted to simplify the routing in the example.

Comment: What an obvious solution! Should have thought of that. Btw, can you answer the bonus question? I'll give your answer an upwote as well ;) - To others, as a consquence I have dropped using Route::resource where I want more control over the url.

Answer (score 1):

### Additional question:

The slugs are dynamically created, which means you don't have prior knowledge about them. Therefore, you can't statically hardcode these into your route. Even if you could, there might be too many of them. So, I think the only way is to use wildcards to capture the navigated URI and then dynamically create the page.

First identify what the base URI for the slugs is: for example for the username of: `<>b4dus3r name<>`(baduser name), you have generated `bdusr-name` slug. You know that this slug is a username slug and you have decided to use the base URI as `example.com/user/`. So to navigate to this user's profile you want: `example.com/user/bdusr-name`.

Add this to your route file: `Route::get('/user/{username},'UserController@show');`

In your `UserController`:

```
public function show($userSlug){
    $user = \App\User::where('userslug','=',$userSlug)->get();
    return view('user.show')->with('user',$user);
}
```

Here I am assuming that the user slug is stored in strings, not a foreign key, in the `userslug` column in the `users` table. In otherwords, you substitute the ID or what have you with the the slug.

Comment: You are a friend of the people. Thanks so much for taking your time write this. It has saved me a ton of time :) I hope you'll have a terrific day!

Comment: Did it answer your question?

Comment: I have asked the slug question again [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787582/using-slugs-in-laravel-5).

If you delete your answer here and repost it there, I'll accept your answer and upvote. I can't give you two right answers in the same thread.

Comment: That's fine. Thank you. I just wanted to know if you think my answer was correct, for my own future reference. Thanks again.