# Using slugs in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5, slug

I have made eloquent-sluggable work on my app. Slugs are saved just fine. Buuuut... How do I use it to create a pretty url?

If possible, I would like to use them in my url instead of ID numbers.

Comment: Basically everything boils down to your routes. You still need to create your routes specifying slugs E.g `Route::get('/home/{slug}'  , function(){ });`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use `slug` in your `route` and generated `url`, for example, if you declare a route something like this:

```
Route::get('users/{username}', 'UserController@profile')->where('profile', '[a-z]+');
```

Then in your controller, you may declare the method like this:

```
public function profile($username)
{
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
}
```

The `username` is your slug here and it must be a string because of `where()...` in the route declaration. If an `integer` is passed then `route` couldn't be found and `404` error will be thrown.

Answer (score 9):

As of Laravel 5.2, if you use Route Model Binding, then you can make your routes that contain the object identifier as usual (*Implicit Binding*). For example:

In `routes/web.php` (Laravel 5.3) or `app/Http/routes.php` (Laravel 5.2):

```
Route::get('categories/{category}', 'CategoryController@show');
```

In your `CategoryController`:

```
show (Category $category) {
    //
}
```

The only thing you need to do is telling Laravel to read the identifier from a different column like, for example, `slug` column, by customizing the key name in your eloquent model:

```
/**
 * Get the route key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

Now, you can refer your `url`'s that requires the object identifier with the `slug` identifier instead the `id` one.

See [Laravel 5.3 (or 5.2) Route Model Biding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-model-binding)

Answer (score 2):

For future readers, as of Laravel 8.0, you can specify a column right in the path

```php
Route::get('/users/{user:slug}', function (User $user) {
    return $user->bio;
});
```