# User friendly URI's with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, seo, uri, user-friendly

At this time, when I view a thread in my Laravel forum, the URL structure looks like this:

```
myforum.com/subforumname/1
```

Whereas 1 represents the id of the forum thread. Ideally, I want it to look like this instead:

```
myforum.com/subforumname/title-of-the-thread-28172
```

The number at the end should not be the id but a unique id consisting of a certain amount of characters instead, like websites usually do.

How would I go about this? Thank you!

Comment: I think this question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787582/using-slugs-in-laravel-5

Comment: define pattern or route in /routes/web.php /subforumname/title-of-the-thread-{uniqueid}